# webservice for android

Tags: android, web-services, sqlite

I'm working on an app that relies heavily on RSS Feeds. I'm not sure on how to manage all the feeds and figured that I should be using a database and a web service. The client would make a request to the server for a feed and the server would send back a json / soap message with necessary data for the client to make an http request for the feed.

Is this a good approach for managing these feeds? I don't think that a local sqllite db would be reasonable option if the data would be constantly changing.

I don't have really fast internet so hosting a webserver isn't an option. Is there a reasonably priced option to host a database that allows for JSON / SOAP services. All that I can find is Amazon's SimpleDB and I'm not sure if this would be the best option.

I'm new to mobile development so your input is appreciated.